# Not Serializable Java

Tags: java, file, computer-science, serializable

I can't figure out why is my class not serializable. As you can see below in my code my class implements Serializable interface.

```
public class Firm {

PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out, true);
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

Set<Worker> workers = new HashSet<>();

boolean saveToFile(){
    String fileName = "text.txt";
    ObjectOutputStream file;
    boolean save = false;
    try{
        file = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
        file.writeObject(workers);
        file.close();
        save = true;
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return save;
}
}

import java.io.Serializable;

public abstract class Worker implements Serializable {//Code
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: what kind of error did you get? and where's the part of code which extends and use your `Pracownik ` class?

Comment: I am not english so I was editing my code while posting it. Now it is Worker class.
java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.Scanner
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)

and so on.

Comment: You should post error information in your question instead of comment. Also I can't reproduce your problem with your current code example so please post proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)/[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Pshemo Is user with `20` rep able to edit his own post?

Comment: Yes, simply use [edit] option under your question. Stack Overflow allows you do change your question (as long as change makes sense) since users with more reputation can easily roll your change back to one of its previous sates for instance if you changed your question into entirely new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `PrintWriter` and the `Scanner` are not serializable; you can't serialize I/O connections like that.

Move those to wherever you're using them, if you need them at all, as local variables.  Don't store them in the class.

Answer (score 0):

You should be assured that all fields in `Worker` class also has type which implements `Serializable` interface.

According to your class names and stacktrace fragment from your commentary, it is most probably you have field with type `Firm` inside `Worker` class which is not serializable due to its structure.

So, you have to do as minimum 2 things:

1) `Firm` class also has to implement `Serializable` interface

2) mark `Scanner` field as `transient`